# What solutions does http://hub.docker.com/ use?

Tags: database, docker, dockerhub

What solutions does http://hub.docker.com/ use?

I’m doing similar in other direction, I wanted to know what technologies were chosen for the implementation of the Docker Hub.

What databases, what framework?

Can you suggest similar open source projects?

Sorry, did not find this information on the net.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming-related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own docker registry server with simple command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart always --name registry registry:2
```

Docker Inc. has open sourced it already:

https://hub.docker.com/_/registry

There is no database involved, normally we use aws s3 bucket as backend to save the images.

There are several other open sources registry servers you can use as well, such as harbor, nexus, etc.